# JAVA: how to load database url from web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, jpa, web.xml

I'm using persistence API and want to load jdbc URL from web.xml. URL should be a context parameter of servlet. I can't find how to construct EntityManagerFactory not using persistence.xml. May be I should create PersistenceUnit in servlet and set some parameters? Can you give me some short example?

Thank you

Comment: May I ask you why you need the JDBC URL to be a context parameter? What are you trying to achieve? If you add some details, you could maybe get more elaborated answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use method `createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties)` of class `javax.persistence.Persistence` .  and  insert all your parameters in the  map

Comment: Yes, I wanted exactly this :)
Thank you :)

Comment: I was always using createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName), I didn't know about another version of this method.

Comment: +1 I totally forgot this method (theoretically, for non managed environments).

Answer (score 1):

I personally find it the cleanest way to define a datasource in the servlet container usng JNDI and refer to that from the persistence.xml.

This also solves one configuration issue when migrating from test-uat-prod as I can use the same datasource name on the machines.

Yeah, I know JNDI is not popular, but this works nice and it avoids having to manipulate hte web.xml which is also wrapped in the war.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact, I have to load JDBC URL from web.xml. I don't think JNDI is good solution for me. I need a very simple way. This is a just homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use a datasource or not, the JPA configuration goes in the `persistence.xml`, not in the `web.xml`. If you want to use JPA, provide a `persistence.xml`.

Comment: To the point! I had the same answer in mind, but I was however a bit unsure and waited until a *Pascal Thivent* was going to post the confirming answer ;)

Comment: @user357255: If it's homework, are you supposed to use JPA? As I wrote in a comment of your question, you should maybe clarify what you need to do exactly.

Comment: quote1: "It's preferred to use JPA, but not necessary".
quote2: "Database connection parameters(URL) should be in web.xml, as servlet context parameter".

So I know how to get this parameters from web.xml. Now, I want to make connection using this URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any value from the web.xml by using env-entry

```xml
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>dbUrl</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>jdbc:url:goes:here</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

And in java

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    String dbUrl= (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/dbUrl");

    //... create your connection
} catch (Exception e ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an init-param in your web.xml that points to your database url. For example, for MySQL, it would be something like this:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>DB_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql:///MY_DB</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Then get this value inside your Web app (in a Servlet) using something like this:

```
String myDbUrl = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("DB_URL");
```

In JSP files you can get the value in this way:

```
String myDbUrl  = config.getInitParameter("DB_URL");
```

Comment: I know this, but it's not clear for me, how to make EntityManagerFactory, with this parameters :(